# Comparando Colunas no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparação

Boa tarde!

Gostaria de saber se vocês conseguem me ajudar. Estou com o seguinte caso, temos um cliente que está com a versão do nosso sistema MUITO desatualizada, com isso está faltando diversas colunas nas tabelas do SQL. Eu queria saber se existe alguma maneira de eu ver todas as colunas que tem em um banco que não existem no outro para poder fazer as alterações necessárias. Tentei procurar no google porém acho que não estava sendo muito claro na pesquisa.

Se alguém souber algum jeito de facilitar essa tarefa sem ter que ser no olho ficaria muito feliz! 
Abraços a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar uma ferramente para compara os bancos de dados.

Uma boa é da [Red-Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) tem uma versão de teste que tem 14 dias de licença gratuita.

Ou [SQLDBDiff](http://www.sqldbtools.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2:sql-tools&catid=2:uncategorised&Itemid=101)

Esta ferramenta está disponível em duas versões:

1. versão freeware: Completamente livre, sem qualquer período de avaliação
2. Versão de shareware com 30 dias de período de teste gratuito, que inclui mais recursos.

versão SQLDBDiff Shareware é a única ferramenta no mercado que inclui a possibilidade de comparar vários bancos de dados ao mesmo banco de dados mestre, tudo em uma única operação.

SQLDBDiff está disponível em Inglês e francês e suporta SQL Server 2014, 2012, 2008, 2005 2000 e SQL Azure.

Todas as ferramentas deste site são desenvolvidos com C #, ADO .Net e SMO. Essas ferramentas são muito seguro e não irá alterar ou criar quaisquer objetos (mesmo temporários) em seus bancos de dados.

Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5 é necessário.

Comment: Baixei esse SQLDBDiff que você falou. Perfeito cara, era exatamente isso! Valeu pela ajuda.